# how to get approval status field value in sharepoint client object model

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-clientobject

How can i get list item approval status value using client object model in sharepoint?

Here is my sample code on fetching other attribute values.

```
ClientContext.Load(listItems,
                    items => items.Include(
                    item => item.Id,
                    item => item.DisplayName,
                    item => item.FileSystemObjectType,
                    item => item.HasUniqueRoleAssignments));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get approve status using like this

```
ClientContext.Load(listItems,
                items => items.Include(
                item => item.Id,
                item => item.DisplayName,
                item => item["Status"]));
```

You can get any of field custom or Sharepoint default fields value like this.

Comment: I know this one. But its not working with status. Not sure why. Suggest another trick. I think CAML query has to fetch it (but it can increase payload size)

Answer (score 2):

Here is the full code that gets and sets (optional) approval status (Possible values for this.oListItem.get_item('_ModerationStatus'): 0 - "Approved", 1 - "Denied",   2- "Pending"):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="/jquery.SPServices-2013.02a.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">


$(document).ready(function () { ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(loadConstants, "sp.js"); });    


function loadConstants() {

    var userid= _spPageContextInfo.userId;
    var requestUri = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/getuserbyid(" + userid + ")";
    var requestHeaders = { "accept" : "application/json;odata=verbose" };
    $.ajax({
      url : requestUri,
      contentType : "application/json;odata=verbose",
      headers : requestHeaders,
      success : onSuccess,
      error : onError
    });

    function onSuccess(data, request){
        var loginName = data.d.Title;

        //get current (selected) list item id
        var docurl = document.URL;
        var beginindex = docurl.indexOf('?ID=') + 4;
        var endindex = docurl.indexOf('&Source=');
        var itemid = docurl.substring(beginindex, endindex);

        var ctx = new SP.ClientContext("your site url");
        var oList = ctx.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('your list name');
        this.oListItem = oList.getItemById(itemid);         

        var appStatus = "";
        ctx.load(this.oListItem);

        ctx.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, function () {  
                                                    //get approval status
                                                    appStatus = this.oListItem.get_item('_ModerationStatus');                                                       

                                                    //set approval status to Approved (0)
                                                    this.oListItem.set_item('_ModerationStatus', 0);
                                                    this.oListItem.update();            

            ctx.executeQueryAsync(
                Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), 
                Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed)
            );

        }),  function (sender, args) { alert('Error occured' + args.get_message());}); 

    }
    function onError(error) {
        alert("error");
    }       
}

</script>
```

Comment: This is java script but i was working with c#. However this has been solved long before. Hope someone else will find it helpful.. Thanks